# How to write the decimal/float format output to file?

Tags: bash, shell

I have output the transformation matrix in hexadecimal format, but I expect the transformation matrices to be in decimal/float format. I use the following bash script to convert the matrix file to decimal format.

Could you tell me how to write the output to file?

The input of the file contains the hexadecimal format and return also the new file which stores decimal format.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read from specified file, or from standard input
infile="${1:-/dev/stdin}"
outfile="${2:-/dev/stdout}"

while read line; do

    for number in $line; do
        a_dec="%f" "$number"
        echo $a_dec >> $outfile
    done
    echo
done < $infile
```

This is my file:

```
0x1.fd654929143fep-1  0x1.c0657a12b37a5p-10  0x1.9666c3b501586p-9  -0x1.6aaea8d2a1c96p-3
-0x1.0c1c057bd3763p-9  0x1.fc236c525c005p-1  0x1.2d69948435847p-7  0x1.47fa54408c064p-2
-0x1.62f5b481dcd5p-9  -0x1.5d517ef6316c2p-7  0x1.01c0feebae85bp+0  0x1.04557b01aefa8p+0
0x0p+0  0x0p+0  0x0p+0  0x1p+0
```

Comment: `/dev/stdout` ?

Comment: Sorry I dod not know. it is result of a software

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Thanks. But it still error `: line 10: a_dec: command not found
`

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ (clue: the spaces around `=`)

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected all error. I ran it and got error `line 10: fg: no job control
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `number` always is a number (and so you don't need to validate it), you can just modify your `a_dec=` assignment to use `printf`. Also, as `printf` can take multiple arguments, the inner loop can be left out:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read from specified file, or from standard input
infile="${1:-/dev/stdin}"
outfile="${2:-/dev/stdout}"

while read line; do

    printf "%f " $line
    echo

    # echo $(printf "%f\n" $line)    # or this to elide the trailing space

done <"$infile" >"$outfile"
```

Comment: Nothing in output. Could you check it?

Comment: Also, I want to write to new file not append when I run the scrip again

Comment: It worked but must add space between number in a line.

Comment: do you care if there is a space at the end of the line?

Comment: No. Just between two number.